# FQL query to fetch a user's Facebook friend's gender PLUS meeting_sex

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fbrequest-form

Not quite as racy as it sounds - I'm using the below code to get a user's male or female friends only and it works fine. However, I also want to check their 'meeting_sex' which is a list of the genders a user's friend is interested in meeting, i.e. male, female or both. (Described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/))

The meeting_sex requires the friends_relationship_details permission which I've added to the graph API explorer, but my output looks like this:

```
"data": [
{
  "name": "ABCDEF", 
  "pic_square": "https://abcdefg.jpg", 
  "sex": "male", 
  "meeting_sex": null, 
  "uid": 123456789
},
```

I.e. the meeting_sex is coming back null. I know the meeting_sex is an array, not just a string, as are the other elements, but why is it coming back null?

I'm new to FQL, and in fact any QL, so once I do get the array to read properly, how do I then make the comparison? i.e so I only return MEN who like WOMEN or MEN who like MEN etc. Here's my current code:

```
NSString *queryString =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name, pic_square, sex, meeting_sex, uid FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND sex = 'male' ORDER BY name"];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: queryString, @"query", nil];

[FBRequest getRequestWithParams:dictionary
                     httpMethod:@"GET" 
                       delegate:self
                     requestURL:@"fql.query"];
```

Thanks for any help :)

Michael

Comment: FYI, my delegates were firing fine when I made the call with [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self]; so it's not an issue related to that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried this on my account and I get nulls for all but one of my friends.  They have an empty array for both the meeting_for and meeting_sex

I've found that some have suggested this is no longer being used:

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=103173

Also, it seems there's a lot of privacy concerns around this:

See https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy Click "Apps and Websites" then "How people bring your info to apps they use"

Also From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getInfo/

```
User Privacy and Visible Data

Important: Depending upon the user's privacy settings (including whether the user has decided to opt out of Platform completely), you may not see certain user data. For any user submitted to this method, the following user fields are visible to an application only if that user has authorized that application and specifically chose to reveal them:

    meeting_for
    meeting_sex
    religion
```

**EDIT**

New in the Graph API's user (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) object:

> **interested_in**
>       The genders the user is interested in. `user_relationship_details` or `friends_relationship_details`. `array` containing strings.

Comment: It seems you are right indeed. I guess it's not really a viable option in the end. Oh well, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Seems there's a new option to retrieve the 'interested_in' sex, from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/. It's an array, but it would still require a user to check the privacy box in 'How people bring your info to apps they use' which I'd imagine most won't have done...

Answer (score 0):

The doc says is requires `user_relashionship_details` **or** `friends_relationship_details`.  I think it would follow that you need to add `user_relashionship_details` to get this detail about the user itself, not just their friends.

Comment: In the Graph API explorer, I have all three tabs of permissions checked, and still don't see it.  So the doc is out of date, or it's a bug.  You should file a bug with facebook to see which of the two they fix. :)

Answer (score 0):

For me i was able to get the data i wanted for "meeting_sex" from the json attribute: 
"gender": "male",
"interested_in": ["female"]

Hope this helps.