# Facebook interested in {gender} returns null

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph, access-token

I'm trying to list all my friend's gender interests, the "Interested in women" for example.

The scope of my token is `basic_info`, `friends_relationship_details`, `friends_relationships`, `public_profile`, `user_friends`, `user_relationship_details`, `user_relationships`.

The `user_relationship_details` correctly allowed me to see my own "interested in" field, but `friends_relationship_details` did not do the same for my friends. They all return `null`.

Full query in fql is `"SELECT uid, name, meeting_for, meeting_sex, relationship_status FROM user WHERE uid='{friend-uid}'"`
I have also tried OpenGraph Explorer with my app's access token and interested_in doesn't show up there either.

Why would this be?

update: Even if a friend has `interested in` privacy as public, my app can't access it.

Comment: Can you post the full request? Graph api or fql? Are you using meeting_sex? In the query?

Comment: Updated to the question, fql and graph, neither works.

Comment: By running a query "SELECT uid, name, meeting_for, meeting_sex, relationship_status FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())" you might see different value than null for some of your friends in the results so it seems to be a facebook issue. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607032/fql-query-to-fetch-a-users-facebook-friends-gender-plus-meeting-sex

Comment: Sadly the subquery didn't change the result. Guess I'll have to wait for facebook to fix it. And the possible duplicate has been updated 2 years ago, all the links are dead and no solution was found.

Comment: It is the same solution that you posted ;) waiting for facebook to fix or file a bug request to their support